# WinForm Show and Hide Puzzle

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having problems showing and hiding two forms.
My app begins by creating a form with one button (btnToggle) and one checkbox  and another form which remains hidden (form2).

I am not getting the behaviour I am expecting which is explained below.

```
  private void btnToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // note that form1 is big enough to contain form2 but form1 not maximised and form2 is not a modal form
        // start with form1 visible form2 not visible chk box not checked
        // click btnToggle and form2 is shown on top of form1
        // click on form1 form2 now behind form1
        // check chksecondFormAlwaysOnTop
        // click btnToggle form2 is shown on top of form1 but 
        // should not go behind form1 when form1 is clicked but it does.
        // what is wrong with the code below.
        // I want form2 to always be on top when chksecondFormAlwaysOnTop
        // is checked but it isnt.
        // My code below:

        if (Form2.Visible && Form2.TopMost) 
        {
            Form2.Hide();
        }
        else if(Form2.Visible && !Form2.TopMost )
        {
            Form2.BringToFront();
        }
        else if (!Form2.Visible && chksecondFormAlwaysOnTop.Checked)
        {
            Form2.Show();
            Form2.TopMost = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Form2.Show();
            Form2.TopMost = false;
        }





    }
```

Comment: Use the Show(owner) overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need is to use the [Form.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) property

> To make a form owned by another form, assign its Owner property a reference to the form that will be the owner.
>
> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the owner form. For example, consider a form named Form2 that is owned by a form named Form1. If Form1 is closed or minimized, Form2 is also closed or hidden.Owned forms are also never displayed behind their owner form. You can use owned forms for windows such as find and replace windows, which should not disappear when the owner form is selected.

Assuming you have the following declaration in your `Form1` class

```
Form2 Form2;
```

Inside your `Form1` load event, put the following

```
Form2 = new Form2 { Visible = false, Owner = this };
```

and then use simple

```
private void btnToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2.Visible = !Form2.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Yes I was getting mighty confused.